# Google Sheets Delete Row if value in a column on one tab to not match a column on other

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am trying to make a script in Google Sheets that will check the values in a column on one tab against the values in a column in another tab.

for example; I would like to have a list allowed e-mail addresses in one tab ("Users") and then, from a form I have it entering addresses in the other tab ("Form1").

If the addresses from the form are not in the Allow list, I would like it to automatically delete that row.

I think my main problem with this code here.

```
if( entryValues[i] === emailsAllowed[t] )
```

Even tho the values in the arrays match it will never become true.

```
function onOpen() 
{

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = sheet.getSheetByName('Form1'); //Get the sheet with the entered records in it.
  var s2 = sheet.getSheetByName('Users');//Get the sheet with the Allow list in it.

  var entryValues = s.getRange('C2:C9').getValues(); //(Get the list of e-mail addresses entered via the form (using their cell reference))
  var emailsAllowed = s2.getRange('A2:A6').getValues(); //(Get the list of allowed e-mail addresses (using their cell reference))
  var isAllowed = 0;

  for(var i = entryValues.length-1; i > 1 ; i--)  // work from the bottom up so when you delete a row it will not miss other rows or delete a row it should not.
  {
    var valueE = entryValues[i] // Test Variable to see what the value is (Can delete this line)
    for(var t = 0; t < emailsAllowed.length; t++) //Loop through all the records in the allow list
    {
      var valueA = emailsAllowed[t] // Test Variable to see what the value is (Can delete this line)
      if( entryValues[i] === emailsAllowed[t] ) // Check to see if there is a match between what was entered and what is in the allow list. //!!! For some reason this line is never true !!!//
      {  isAllowed = 1;} //if it is there set a variable isAllowed to 1 (to indicate that there is a match)
    }

    if( isAllowed === 1 ) 
    {isAllowed = 0; }// if there was a match set isAllowed back to 0, ready for the next run
    else
    {
      s.deleteRows(i) //if there was no match (and isAllowed is not set) delete the invalid row.
    }  
  }
}
```

Thanks

**UPDATE: This here is the working code:  Thanks to (Sandy Good)**

```
function onOpen() 
{

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var s = sheet.getSheetByName('Form1'); //Get the sheet with the entered records in it.
  var s2 = sheet.getSheetByName('Users');//Get the sheet with the Allow list in it.

  var entryValues = s.getRange('C2:C9').getValues().join().split(","); //(Get the list of e-mail addresses entered via the form (using their cell reference))
  var emailsAllowed = s2.getRange('A2:A6').getValues().join().split(","); //(Get the list of allowed e-mail addresses (using their cell reference))

  var isAllowed = 0; // Create the variable isAllowed and set it to 0 (this will be used to leave the row if it matches)

  for(var i = entryValues.length-1; i > 1 ; i--)  // work from the bottom up so when you delete a row it will not miss other rows or delete a row it should not.
  {
    var valueE = entryValues[i] // Test Variable to see what the value is (Can delete this line)
    for(var t = 0; t < emailsAllowed.length; t++) //Loop through all the records in the allow list
    {
      var valueA = emailsAllowed[t] // Test Variable to see what the value is (Can delete this line)
      if( entryValues[i] === emailsAllowed[t] ) // Check to see if there is a match between what was entered and what is in the allow list. //!!! For some reason this line is never true !!!//
      {  isAllowed = 1;} //if it is there set a variable isAllowed to 1 (to indicate that there is a match)
    }

    if( isAllowed === 1 ) 
    {isAllowed = 0; }// if there was a match set isAllowed back to 0, ready for the next run
    else
    {
      s.deleteRow(i+2) //if there was no match (and isAllowed is not set) delete the invalid row. (+ 2 because the rows start from 1 and they also have a heading (the the array starts from 0))
    }  
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `getValues()` method returns a two dimensional array.  You are not getting the inner array value.  The code is not comparing value to value, it's comparing an array to an array.  The inner array only has one value in it, but it's still an array.

You need to get the values out of the two dimensional array.  Currently the code looks like this:

```
var entryValues = s.getRange('C2:C9').getValues();
var emailsAllowed = s2.getRange('A2:A6').getValues();
```

To convert the 2D array to a regular array, do this:

```
var entryValues = s.getRange('C2:C9').getValues().join().split(",");
var emailsAllowed = s2.getRange('A2:A6').getValues().join().split(",");
```

This method can be used because there is only one value in each inner array, and that is because you are only getting one column.  If you were getting multiple columns, that technique will not work.

```
twoDArray = [ [innerValue], [innerValueTwo], [inner3] ]
```